# Theory of calculating randomness for damping factor

Tags: python, physics

I am referring, as an example, to Blender's particle collision system, where you can set the randomness for particle damping between 0.0 and 1.0. My question now is: how does it exactly work? Yes, there will be a random number between 0.0 and 1.0 but how is it applied to the damping factor? I want to create something similar in Java and therefore I want to fully understand the calculation behind that. Is the random factor the probability p and the calculation something like a gaussian distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
public Vector3f damping(Vector3f vector) 
{
    float random = (float) (this.randomDamp*(Math.random()*2-1));
    float clampedValue = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (1-damp)+random)); //clamp between 0 and 1
    vector.scale(clampedValue);
    return vector;
}
```

With a factor of 0.5 and a random factor of 1, the final factor will vary between -0.5 (0) and 1.5 (1)